# Database multiple selection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've the following 2 tables:

Players

```
  id name
  p1  name1
  p2  name2
  p3  name3
  p4  name4
```

Matches

```
  id winner loser
  m1   p1    p2
  m2   p3    p4
```

what i want is to write a select statement that will return the following:

```
  id  name  matches wins
  p1 name1   1      1
  p3 name3   1      1
  p2 name2   1      0
  p4 name4   1      0
```

this is basically to return the tournament standings, ordered by number of wins.

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using and any attempts you have made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses correlated subqueries:

```
select p.*,
       (select count(*) from matches m where p.id in (m.winner, m.loser)
       ) as matches,
       (select count(*) from matches m where p.id = m.winner
       ) as wins
from players p
order by wins desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use two outer joins:

```
select p.id, 
       p.name,
       count(distinct m.id) as matches,
       count(distinct w.id) as wins
from players p
  left join matches m on p.id in (m.winner, m.loser)
  left join matches w on w.winner = p.id
group by p.id, p.name
order by wins desc, p.name
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add 2 columns to Players table or create new table Tournament named. You can register Tournament Players with your hand(manually) on your admin panel.
If will you add 2 columns to Players table. U will query Players win scores, after query get your MySQL number of rows function and you will get hoe much win The Player. After writenitnto Tournament page. (Note: Sorry for bad English, im trying to speak English. Please try to understand me.)